# Thermal energy of the heated water

Tags: thermodynamics

If I have a thermal source of an energy (hot water) and its volume is $V$ and its temperature is $T_1$ and the source is open and the environment's temperature is $T_2$, how can I get the energy that the source produces till it reaches the temperature $T_2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the mass m of the water times its specific heat capacity at constant pressure Cp times the temperature difference (T2-T1) in degrees absolute. Be sure to check your units.

Comment: Thank you, I just was not able to put the theory into the equation, especially for the equillibrium examples.